# Xamarin iOS deploy to device results in 'mscorlib.dll couldn't not be found'

Tags: build, xamarin.ios, mscorlib

While deploying my application on iOS Simulator it works without any problems, but when I attached iPhone 5 on the Mac, deploying to that device results in following errors from Visual Studio's debug console:

```
Tool /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch execution started with arguments: --cache [... paths and arguments ...]
AOT Compilation exited with code 1, command:
MONO_PATH= [...path...]

The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.
1>  It should have been installed in the `/Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/builds/install/cross64/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll' directory.

Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(696,3): error : Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/blagoja/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MobApp.iOS/1be55aeb91c215df9342d3daa452982b/C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/vsF8C6.tmp/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build/System.dll'
```

So fifth sentence (or sixth line) is saying that 'mscorlib.dll' could not be found at specified path, but from showed path where it should reside, on my mac i see only first directory 'Users'... nothing else.

So yeah, i belive i should put there the 'mscorlib.dll' but copy-paste is the right choice?

Also i managed to find multiple versions for mscorlib.dll into `Developer/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/{version}/lib/mono/{mono_versions}/mscordlib.dll`. So maybe the configuration has path mismatches?